# Нужен ли специальный allocator в .so библиотеке на си используемой из Python

Tags: python, c

Могу ли я использовать в python функцию из динамической библиотеки которая вызывает malloc и free внутри себя? Мне не нужен другой, специальный, аллокатор или что-то? Или и так безопасно работать будет?

Comment: Да, можете. Специальный аллокатор не нужен.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Пожалуйста ответом оформите.